# Unicode composition in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, arabic, ligature

I am looking for a way to count ligatures as single units as they are displayed to user, e.g. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FEFB.

When this character is typed (type G on Arabic keyboard), it's inserted in decomposition form, i.e. `U+0644 U+0627`.

I'm able to decompose `U+FEFB` by

```
escape(String.fromCodePoint(0xFEFB).normalize("NFKD")) // '%u0644%u0627'
```

Is there a way to compose `U+0644 U+0627` into `0xFEFB`?

Why this does work?

```
escape(String.fromCodePoint(0x0644, 0x0627).normalize("NFKC"))
```

The only idea I has was to iterate over unicode ranges I'm interested in, decompose and create a map, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: chars -> ligature is not a function (in the math sense), because there can be multiple ligatures decomposing to the same chars. In your case, lam+alef can be isolated (FEFB) or final (FEFC) and there's no way for the composer to know what you need.

Comment: @georg Thanks a lot, now it makes complete sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [the ES2019 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-string.prototype.normalize) requires the implementation to:

> Let ns be the String value that is the result of normalizing S into the normalization form named by f as specified in https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/.

and given that https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/NormalizationTest.txt describes that character as

```
FEFB;FEFB;FEFB;0644 0627;0644 0627; # (ﻻ; ﻻ; ﻻ; لا; لا; ) ARABIC LIGATURE LAM WITH ALEF ISOLATED FORM
```

it is the compliant behaviour. See

```
# 1. The following invariants must be true for all conformant implementations
#
#    NFC
#      c2 ==  toNFC(c1) ==  toNFC(c2) ==  toNFC(c3)
#      c4 ==  toNFC(c4) ==  toNFC(c5)
#
#    NFD
#      c3 ==  toNFD(c1) ==  toNFD(c2) ==  toNFD(c3)
#      c5 ==  toNFD(c4) ==  toNFD(c5)
#
#    NFKC
#      c4 == toNFKC(c1) == toNFKC(c2) == toNFKC(c3) == toNFKC(c4) == toNFKC(c5)
#
#    NFKD
#      c5 == toNFKD(c1) == toNFKD(c2) == toNFKD(c3) == toNFKD(c4) == toNFKD(c5)
```

No normalisation converts either `c4` or `c5` form back to `c1`, or `c2`, or `c3`.

So to my unicode-amateur opinion there is no standard-compliant way to normalise `U+0644 U+0627` back to `U+FEFB`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was lazy and didn't dig deep enough. Make sense now.